# Java- Inheritrance issue. Accessing subclass methods on an object array initially instantiated off the super()

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, subclass

I'm taking a java class and im having some trouble understanding inheritance.
I'm not asking for you guys to do any coding for me but pointing me in the right direction would go a long ways. (wouldn't let me use the homework or schoolwork tags but i wanted to be upfront with what i was asking)

Basically i'm writing a banking application with a class called Account that acts as the super constructor for two subclasses called Checking and Savings.

It's my understanding that if i instantiate an array of the Account object i can then call the sub-class (which in turn calls the superclass constructor with some minute differences in arguments) and using the new command assign it to some position of the object array.

My issue then is accessing certain methods in the subclass.  The compiler still sees the object array as Account but i want it to access methods that belong to either the Checking or Savings subclass.

My question is would making the Account an abstract class work out better?  or would it be possible to declare a method in the Account Class and the subclass' and if i call the Account method would it be able to differentiate between which subclass method to call in turns?

I'm trying to avoid using typecasting into the subclass where possible and trying to keep the Account subclass as generic and encapsulated as possible.

Any help would be appreciated.  I can write pseudocode if you need references but i would rather rather do all the coding on my own.

Comment: sounds like, interface is your friend here.

Comment: Your clean solution would be to design it so that `Account` has all the functions you need and that these are overridden by your sub classes. This way you dont need to cast

Comment: Edit : I see your last but 3 paragraph is asking about exactly this. Take a look at what [virtual functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) are. They are not refered to in java world as such, but when you over ride a base class function, you are using this concept

Comment: Heya guys,

After reading up more closely on abstract methods and the @Override command i think i've gotten it down.  Thanks for your help guys i really appreciate you guys pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are reusable functions with full body or properties/instance variables to be declared in the Account class, make that an abstract class. If there are only contracts (or methods that need to be implemented by the child classes), make that an interface. By using an interface, the best advantage I can think of is in testing where you can mock out the behaviors (contracts) or in the future extend some other classes. Once you extend a class, you can no longer extend from another one (multiple inheritance is not allowed).

In either case, you will not be able to instantiate the base class.

Comment: You are right, i ended up turning my original object class into an abstract method and ran into compiler errors when trying to instantiate it.  I instead just didn't instantiate the array and used "new" subclass constructors do the heavy lifting for me.

I've gotten it down now and the program performs and fucntions as i want it to.  Now just fix the logic errors in some mutators and i'm all good done.  Thank you for the information i greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: The next step is to read up on Head First Design Patterns. That will explain the pros and cons of doing things certain ways. That book may be old, but the practices aren't.